# Azure Automation Runbook, can it call web api through a VNet?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-automation, azure-deployment-slots

First question is:  Is my understanding and my company's current usage of Azure Automation correct?

We have a web app running on Azure production slot.  There is an Azure Automation Runbook that is configured to run once a week.  In the runbook script, it first authenticates with the app running on the slot and then calls the weekly batch process.  This is all using public IPs.

My goal is to create another automation that will run on the development slot.  The development slot runs on an Azure virtual network.  While it does have a public IP address, I am trying to configure things so that all the internal network traffic stays on the Vnet.  In all my searching I have not seen any documentation about how to get an Automation Runbook to execute in a defined Azure Virtual Network.  This is leading me to believe that our current usage of Automation Runbooks is not how it was designed to work.

Q1: Are Azure Automation Runbooks designed to be able to call a web service on an Azure Virtual Network?

Q2: If Yes to Q1, how should that be configured?

Q3: If No to Q1, what is the correct way of having the Azure Automation Runbook trigger the batch process within the Application slot?

Answer (score 0):

If your slot doesn't have public IP I guess you used Private Endpoint.

So if you want your runbook to access resource in private network you should use private link.

You will find more information here - [Use Azure Private Link to securely connect networks to Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/private-link-security)

> Azure Private Endpoint is a network interface that connects you privately and securely to a service powered by Azure Private Link. Private Endpoint uses a private IP address from your VNet, effectively bringing the Automation service into your VNet. Network traffic between the machines on the VNet and the Automation account traverses over the VNet and a private link on the Microsoft backbone network, eliminating exposure from the public internet.

Comment: Ok, so the slot does actually have a public IP address, we use a bunch of firewall rules to control access, not an ideal approach.  This is why I am going down this path of learning how to get the Automation on the Vnet.  I did see the link you gave, but the way it was worded and the way the first diagram was created it implies they allow an application call an Automation, not the Automation calling the application.  Does it go both ways?

Comment: Yes. The connection works in both directions.

Comment: Thank you, I will read through the whole thing, thank you!!!